# Bootstrap table-stripped confusing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm totally confused with bootstrap's table styling. I try to get background-alternating rows by applying table-striped class but it has no effect.
Actually I googled some examples with live css on the page but there is no table striping too!

Take for example http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_striped&stacked=h

It says "Striped Rows example" but there is no striped rows. May be something wrong with my browser? All of them...

Comment: Either you're using IE8 which doesn't support `nth-child(odd)` used for the striped table or the contrast of your monitor is way off.

Comment: I have Chrome and IE 9. A supid question but anyway: do you see stripes at the link above?

Comment: I can see the stripes, I've copied the code from your link into http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/emEQrL and make the stripes get a pink background. See if you can see those.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the page on a different machine? Something must be wrong with yours if there's no difference between `#fff` and `#f9f9f9`. You can always inspect the elements and see what's their current `background-color` property set to.

Comment: OK, seriously. Add the line `<style>  .table-striped>tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td {background-color:#000} </style>` to the W3Schools code block (just before the `</head>`) and click "See Result". Do you still not see zebra stripes?

Comment: By the way, while W3Schools calls them zebra stripes, the stripes are actually horizontal rather than vertical.